# How can i get my function arguments to be of the corrct type for datatables in r?

Tags: r, function, input, datatables, eval

I have a data table called *data*:

[![This is a screengrab of the data table][1]][1]

The goal is to write a function that mimics the following code:

```
data[Region == "Northeast",mean(Awareness, na.rm = TRUE), by = Product][order(-rank(V1))][1:5,.(Product)]
```

So far I have:

```
topx_engagement = function(state_of_engagement, respondent_variable, respondent_variable_sub, rank_length = 3){
  
  respondent_variable_sub = as.character(respondent_variable_sub)
  
  data[eval(respondent_variable == respondent_variable_sub), mean(get(state_of_engagement), na.rm = TRUE), by = Product][order(-rank(V1))][1:rank_length,.(Product)]
}
```

The function **topx_engagement** should allow a user to enter **respondent_variable** which coincides with *Region*, a **respondent_variable_sub** which coincides with *"Northeast"* and subsequent arguments. I would like to focus on the preceding arguments as all the other work fine.

Currently, when I call:

```
topx_engagement(state_of_engagement = Awareness, respondent_variable = Region, respondent_variable_sub = Northeast, rank_length = 3)
```

I get an error:

**Error in topx_engagement(state_of_engagement = Awareness, respondent_variable = Region,  :
object 'Northeast' not found**

Alternately, running

```
topx_engagement = function(state_of_engagement, respondent_variable, respondent_variable_sub, rank_length = 3){
  
  #respondent_variable_sub = as.character(respondent_variable_sub)
  
  data[eval(respondent_variable == respondent_variable_sub), mean(get(state_of_engagement), na.rm = TRUE), by = Product][order(-rank(V1))][1:rank_length,.(Product)]
}

topx_engagement(state_of_engagement = Awareness, respondent_variable = Region, respondent_variable_sub = Northeast, rank_length = 3)
```

throws an error of **Error in eval(.massagei(isub[[2L]]), parent.frame(), parent.frame()) : object 'Region' not found**

I need assistance with getting the function inputs in the right format.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hseWS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `deparse/substitute` to convert to `character` string if we are passing unquote arguments

```
topx_engagement = function(state_of_engagement, 
     respondent_variable, respondent_variable_sub, rank_length = 3){
  
  state_of_engagement <- deparse(substitute(state_of_engagement))
  respondent_variable <- deparse(substitute(respondent_variable))
  respondent_variable_sub <- deparse(substitute(respondent_variable_sub))
 
 
  
  
  data[eval(as.name(respondent_variable)) == respondent_variable_sub, 
        mean(get(state_of_engagement), na.rm = TRUE), 
           by = Product][order(-rank(V1))][1:rank_length,.(Product)]
}
```

then call it as

```
topx_engagement(state_of_engagement = Awareness, 
   respondent_variable = Region, 
       respondent_variable_sub = Northeast, rank_length = 3)
```